# Flutter search text through ListView.Builder and highlight match

Tags: flutter, search, flutter-listview

Basically I have a reading application where huge text is displayed on the screen and for optimization I've split up the text by \n and displayed in a ListView.Builder.

This text's font size and font weight can be changed by the user at any time (from 12 to 24, from w200 to w900)

So, goal is to implement a search bar, scroll to the matched text and highlight it (just like the chrome does)

example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:testtttt/search_bar.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: App()));

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  App({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _lorem =
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam rhoncus mauris ac neque interdum porta. Integer rutrum est a velit gravida eleifend. Sed quis eros a eros imperdiet mollis semper sit amet erat. In in gravida nunc. Maecenas id arcu sed sem commodo sodales ut a arcu. Morbi quis nisl varius, vestibulum libero eget, egestas diam. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed ut porta metus. Ut venenatis nibh et leo efficitur, et tempor urna euismod. Maecenas quis quam nec leo egestas tempus.\nDonec dapibus, mi et hendrerit sodales, ligula ex suscipit est, vel varius ex ligula at erat. Duis scelerisque aliquam felis, sed accumsan lacus maximus sit amet. Suspendisse ac nulla purus. Cras diam leo, luctus eu laoreet non, sollicitudin a turpis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Quisque efficitur auctor fermentum. Nulla non luctus ligula, at sollicitudin nulla. Aliquam pellentesque nisi in blandit condimentum. Etiam vitae felis ac nisl eleifend tristique eget vitae nulla. In rhoncus venenatis tempus. Donec tortor diam, lobortis eu ex vitae, viverra hendrerit nisi.\nPraesent sollicitudin vulputate augue, cursus vestibulum sem volutpat non. Donec efficitur est a erat sodales, et aliquam dui vehicula. Quisque eu purus malesuada augue efficitur fringilla id vitae nunc. Cras eget diam sit amet mi posuere convallis. Nulla facilisi. Maecenas sit amet dapibus nisi. Donec tincidunt dui pulvinar lorem malesuada posuere. Nunc tristique facilisis pretium. Pellentesque tristique purus ipsum, at dapibus magna eleifend sed. Vestibulum lacinia augue sed ipsum facilisis rutrum. Proin feugiat feugiat auctor.\nNunc pellentesque libero lectus, non maximus massa maximus at. Sed elementum metus ac odio fringilla bibendum. Mauris facilisis dictum justo, quis molestie nulla vestibulum quis. Donec in sodales justo, quis pulvinar metus. Nulla id suscipit nisi. Praesent volutpat sollicitudin facilisis. Vivamus risus justo, dignissim vel turpis id, commodo tincidunt ligula.\nSed at purus dui. Suspendisse quis sem eu libero fringilla condimentum nec vitae orci. Sed mi augue, bibendum non consectetur dictum, ultricies eget est. Suspendisse porta arcu sit amet sem interdum laoreet. Nulla facilisi. Vestibulum tincidunt urna tempor, finibus enim sodales, dapibus erat. Curabitur vitae iaculis lectus, a consectetur quam. Donec sed auctor sem. Etiam in metus ut tortor viverra euismod. Sed porta et nisl id consequat. In consequat elit ex, a tristique quam consequat ac. Maecenas euismod sodales consequat.";
  final List<String> _splitLorem = _lorem.split(RegExp('\n'));

  static const FontWeight _userChangeableFontWeight = FontWeight.bold;
  static const double _userChangeableFontSize = 16.0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            SearchBar(
              onChanged: (value) {
                // search, scroll to and highlight the matched values
              },
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'Search...',
                counterText: '',
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 16),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 12),
                itemCount: _splitLorem.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Text(
                    _splitLorem[index],
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: _userChangeableFontSize,
                      fontWeight: _userChangeableFontWeight,
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: use `RichText` for such text highlighting

Comment: It's not clear what your question is exactly. How to implement search (logic), how to highlight text (ui). These are likely 2 separate actions.

Comment: Hint:  you can't really search in a listview builder. Searching is one thing, it's a function. Then presenting the search result is another thing, that can be handled by the listview builder

Comment: so bellow is a chapter of a book and I want to type some text in a field and then automatically scroll to the matching keyword present it the chapter

It's a similar functionality to chrome's "find in page"
you type a keyword and it scrolls and highlights to matched ones on the web page

Comment: Thanks @pskink! Scrollable.ensureVisible is all I needed

Comment: I've found a package [scrollable positioned list](https://pub.dev/packages/scrollable_positioned_list) that I can use for this purpose

Comment: "I've found a package scrollable_positioned_list" - thanks, good to know...

Answer (score 0):

```dart
// Assuming you have a search bar, with a listener of some sorts
// e.g.: TextFormField with onChanged that calls setState(){} 
//
// Your search function could be simply
List<String> matches = _splitLorem.where((word) => word == searchTerm);
```